# Symfony 2 error handling exceptions vs flashbag

Tags: symfony, error-handling

I see that in most Symfony 2 examples when eg a record does not exist, Symfony 2 throws an exception. I do not find such an approach friendly for the end user. Why should someone prefer throwing an exception and not add some error messages at the flashbag?

Answer (score 1):

In the examples it generally throws an exception with

```
throw $this->createNotFoundException('Message');
```

which redirects the user to the 404 error page.

In a CMS, if the record is not found you probably want to show the user a 404 page as opposed to adding an error to the flash bag and redirecting them to, lets say, the homepage.

I guess it depends on your applications needs, and how you want to handle it.